# Detect Change in Active Worksheet - OfficeJS

Tags: excel, office-js

I know that I can monitor the active selection by adding an event handler with `workbook.onSelectionChanged` and deriving the worksheet from the selection address, but this seems to slow down / diminish UX in Excel Online. Is there a way for me to specifically monitor when the active worksheet is changed, as opposed to every change in selection? I'm not able to find any clear documentation online for the available event handlers I can use with OfficeJS.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a different way to monitor selection for specific types of selections. Today it's necessary to use `workbook.onSelectionChanged` for any selection-change detection. We're working on improvements here but I don't have a specific timeline to share.

-Michael (PM for add-ins)